# getting related data from sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

So my table is called prereqTable and looks something like

```
JobID   prereq
job254  job111
job345  job254
job432  job345
```

I need to find a query that returns all prereq for a job. Example: If I want prereqs for job432 they would be: job111, job254, job345

so prereq `where jobid = "job432"`   is job345.. I need to somehow query job 345, then job254, and stop when there are no prereqs left.

Any ideas???

Comment: What database server are you using? The query can be significantly different for SQL Server and MySQL, for example.

Comment: I am using sql server

Comment: Cross join? That would return all prereq jobs with a JobID if thats what you are looking for.

Comment: That's a recursive query.  This article might help : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Comment: Not sure if a cross join would really achieve what I'm doing, the recursive query sounds good, i'm familiar with recursion.. just not in sql, I guess I'll read up on recursive cte unless anyone else can think of an easier solution.

Comment: This is not a cross join, this is a recursive query and this has been answered literally 100s of times.  Vote to close.

Comment: Agreed. @user1726845, it is wise to take a look at JonH's link and adjust it to your needs. Please feel free to close this question and open a new question with details if you have troubles adapting the query.